# json_populate_record Performance Issues

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgres 9.4 and using json_populate_record function with type which has 60 columns defined.
The table with the json, old_table, has 100,000 records and it takes over 2 minutes to do the following parse and insert command:

```
select (json_populate_record(null::v_type, row_to_json_output)).*
into new_table
from from old_table
```

Can I optimize it in any way? Alternatives? Are newer versions better in doing it?

Thanks

Comment: What is `row_to_json_output`? That looks suspicious.

Comment: You should show your actual statement and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it. Why do you want to use JSON?

Comment: "Limit  (cost=0.00..382.50 rows=1000 width=4508) (actual time=4.429..13151.684 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=199"
"  ->  Seq Scan on vsats_json  (cost=0.00..35643.08 rows=93184 width=4508) (actual time=4.426..13149.898 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=199"
"Planning Time: 0.206 ms"
"Execution Time: 13224.286 ms"

Comment: I ran it this time with only 1000 just to get the plan.  I tried to use jsonb / json_populate_record and performance was even worse.  I thought of having one generic table for auditing, but performance may force me to have individual tables with separate fields instead of one field with JSON structure.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In my hands, using jsonb_populate_record with jsonb values is about 40% faster than using json_populate_record with json values.

Starting in v11, this statement could run in parallel.  However, the cost estimate of the function json_populate_record is very low, so to get it to actually choose parallelization, you should probably do something like:

```
alter function json_populate_record cost 1000;
```

And the same with jsonb_populate_record.

But really, why are you doing this often enough to care if it takes 2 minutes?  Certainly cycling data back and forth between table to json and back to table on a routine ongoing basis surely doesn't make much sense.